# How to implement array type route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement an array type route in Laravel 5.8.
Here's what I tried:

```
Route::get('/','/myroute', 'MyController@index');
Route::get(['/','/myroute'], 'MyController@index');
Route::get([('/','/myroute')], 'MyController@index');
Route::get('/' || '/myroute', 'MyController@index');
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to create a route with an "OR" condition.
Let's say I want to access MyController `index` using **`mydomain.dev/`** or **`mydomain.dev/myroute`** but I am getting a **404|Not Found**.

Tried to read the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing) but I can't find something that points me to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the example which you want to implement.

```
Route::get('/{param?}', 'MyController@index')
    ->where('param', '(myroute|myroute2)');
```

By above route you can create following urls for the same controller function

```
www.site.com/
www.site.com/myroute
www.site.com/myroute2
```

Try this I think this will help you.

Answer (score 6):

```
Route::get('/{myroute?}', function () {
    echo 'test';
})
    ->where('myroute', '(myroute|mysecondroute)');
```

This is an example. you define in your route a variable that can take the values you have in your where clase

That means that endpoints

```
api/myroute 
api/
api/mysecondroute
```

will access the same routing and elaborating the same controller

Comment: `{myroute}` should be optional though I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign array as route (aka. first argument in the get method), it should be a string. If you need 2 route to go the same controller, define 2 separate routes for that.

```
Route::get('/route', 'Controller@method');
Route::get('/another-route', 'Controller@method');
```

Comment: yeah, this is the same idea given by @Mihkel

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel Router](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html) does not provide the functionality but as it's [Macroable](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.html) you can add a simple macro to solve the situation. I'll provider an example below.

In `RouteServiceProvider` or any serviceprovider really, register a macro:

```
Route::macro('gets', function(array $urls, $action) {
     foreach($urls as $url) {
          Route::get($url, $action);
     }
}
```

Now use it as following in your `routes.php`

```
Route::gets(['/', '/myroute'], 'MyController@index')
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want to do it the way I explained above

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining a route that redirects to another URI, you may use the `Route::redirect` method:

```
Route::redirect('/here', '/there');
```

Comment: no, what I need is to define routes for one controller not to redirect